# Networking not working at all

Tags: networking, dual-boot

So I have recently decided to dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I am also fairly new to a Linux environment.  So far it seems I am having the worst time trying to get any sort of network connection.  Everything works fine on Windows but when I shutdown and restart to Ubuntu, nothing works  Not only is wireless not working but neither is a wired connection.  All I have done is install Ubuntu to a separate hard drive.  From the get go no networking has worked.  I have searched online and tried a variety of solutions to no avail.

- Complete shutdown (not restart) from Windows, then boot to Ubuntu
- Complete shutdown (not restart) from Ubuntu, then boot to Ubuntu
- I have tried executing "ipconfig /release" on windows before a complete shutdown
- I have checked to make sure Ubuntu recognizes my Ethernet and WiFi hardware
- Setting the NetworkManager.conf "managed" to true
- Restarted the network manager with "sudo systemctl restart network-manager"

I am at a complete loss at this point, if anyone has any ideas, I would love to try them...

Networking stuff:

- Wireless card Qualcomm Atheros AR9287
- Ethernet is Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411

*Update*:
I have also tried

- blacklisting acer-wmi
- adding "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" to /etc/modprobe.d/ath9.conf
- I have also changed the file from above to ath9k.conf

However, now it seems that sometimes some networks such as a printer and a random network show up briefly then disappear

*Update 2*:
Network drivers:

- Ethernet: r8169
- Wireless: ath9k

Comment: How do you know that you do not have a network connection? Check the output of ``ip -a``. Does your network device show up? Does it have an IP address? If so, is the problem with name resolution? ``ping ubuntu.com``.  Also try ``systemctl status systemd-networkd``.  Poke about a bit. ``journalctl`` will have useful information. ``journalctl | grep network`` for example.

Comment: So far I have not been able to establish a connection via ethernet (an messege keeps poping up that says it was unable to connect) and no wifi networks are shown in the connection dialog.  unfortunatly it is a little hard for me to poke about because I am unfamiliar with a lot of linux as I am just getting into it.  I tried the commands you suggested and all it seems I can find out is from the status command.  It says Loaded: loaded (systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor present: enabled)  Active: inactive

Comment: ``sudo lshw -class network``. This should show you have network devices. ``sudo iwconfig`` This should show you have wireless network devices. So ``ip -a`` shows nothing? No return at all?

Comment: I have run the commands and posted the outputs [here](https://postimg.cc/gallery/11bihlecm/).  Unfortunately most of the results don't make too much sense to me...

Comment: You seem to be in pretty good shape hardware-wise.  Please: Rather than posting images, it is better to copy the output into your question. There is an option to edit it. When you paste you can format the display using markdown (see help).

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes I was wondering what the best way was to post the output of the terminal, will do next time!

Comment: ```lspci -v > lspci.out` Then open lspci.out to find Ethernet controller and Network controller. Note that each listing will have a 'Driver' field. What drivers are listed?